# Access Denied to network path when run as service

Tags: .net

This code:

```
Using reader As IO.StreamReader = IO.File.OpenText("\\10.31.42.249\share\file.txt") ...
```

is giving me this error:

> Access to the path '\\10.31.42.249\share\file.txt' is denied.

when I run it as a windows service. The same code in a console application on the same PC works fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a rights issue. You should make the service run by a user that has rights on that share, probably a network user with minimal rights. You should check:

1. The service credentials;
2. The rights issued on the file share on the server.

Comment: On the money mate. I changed the service credentials to Network Service and it worked fine. Thanks!